# Programmatically add users to Secure Store Service in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, secure-store

I've set up SQL credentials in my site's Secure Store Service and would like to add people to the members of this group programmatically (using C#) but am having trouble with the API.  I've found some references but I can't seem to find where some things exist (specifically ISecureStoreServiceContext http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.securestoreservice.server.isecurestoreservicecontext.aspx which uses a .dll I can't find in /Common Files/microsoft shared/Web Server Extensions/15/ISAPI).  Although I do see Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.Security.dll but this only seems to give me part of the API.  Does anyone have an up-to-date solution for SharePoint 2013 to add users in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll, which is in the GAC.  You can paste this when creating the reference:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll
```

Comment: +1 thanks for this John! I was looking in the windows/assembly and couldn't find it.